# Minimum and maximum value of function $f(x,y,z) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find minimum and maximum value of function $$f(x,y,z) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3$$ on set $$ \left\{ (x,y,z):  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1  \wedge x+y+z =  \sqrt{3} \right\} $$

I don't know what is this set. We have sphere and plane so I suppose that it may be circle or point. How find it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: Yes, I'm. I supposed that this method will fail. But I used it, and received that we have only one critical point: $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$.

Comment: The Lagrange equations all look the same, except for the change of variable in each one, so it is not surprising to conclude that $ \ x = y = z \ . $  The situation here, however, is that the intersection of the constraint unit sphere and the constraint plane $ \ x+y+z \ = \  \sqrt{3} \ $ is _only_ the single point that you found.  So the Lagrange result is consistent with this, but then there is _only one_ critical point, which gives both the maximum and minimum value for the function, $ \ 3·(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})^3 \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \ . $

Comment: [continued]  I wondered when I saw this problem whether the person posing it made an error in one of the conditions, or whether they set up the intersection this way deliberately to see whether the students were paying attention...

Answer (score 3):

note 
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+1+1)\ge (x+y+z)^2$$
so if
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x+y+z=\sqrt{3}$$
then we have
$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=(x+y+z)^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=0$$
so 
$x=y=z$

Answer (score 0):

The mean of the square is greater or equal to the square of the mean, with equality only when all the values are equal. According to the constraint, both the mean of the square and the square of the mean are equal to $\frac13$, so the only values consistent with the constraint are x=y=z.